# "Invariance" of Pearson's Chi-squared test

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

A company has 100 employees, 40 women and 60 men.

At the end of the year, the company decides to give bonuses to 20 people: 16 men and 4 women.

I'm asked to find a way to test the presence of a connection between the gender and the bonus attribution.

I thought to use a standard Pearson's Chi-squared test, hence building the following table:

| Received bonus | $O_i$ | $E_i$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Men | 16 | 12 |
| Women | 4 | 8 |

$O_i$ is the observed frequency for the two categories and $E_i$ is the expected one, assuming the bonus attribution does not depend on gender (and all employees have similar features if not for the gender).

I proceed to calculate the $\chi^2$ statistics as follows:
$$\chi^2 = \frac{(16-12)^2}{12} + \frac{(4-8)^2}{8} = 3.\overline{3}$$

And then (since $\chi^2_{(0,05, 1)} \approx 3,841$) I can conclude that I cannot refuse the null hypothesis of independence between *gender* and *bonus attribution* at a level of significance of $0.05$ (I can refuse the null hypothesis at a level of significance of $0.1$, though).

---

**[MY QUESTION]**

Assuming all I did is correct (please tell me if it's not!), I wondered if testing for the independence between *gender* and *NOT receiving a bonus* should yield to the same conclusion and I concluded that it must do so! (right?)

So, I built the following table for the character *bonus NOT received*:

| NOT received bonus | $O_i$ | $E_i$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Men | 44 | 48 |
| Women | 36 | 32 |

Now, calculating the Pearson's chi-squared statistics from this I get $\chi^2=0.8\overline{3}$. This statistics brings me to different conclusions from the previous ones: for example, now I cannot refuse the null hypothesis with a level of significance $0.1$!

What am I doing wrong? Am I testing for two **different** things without realizing it?

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Comment: I forgot  to state the conclusion: your test is significant but not highly significant, being your pvalue in the middle between 5% and 1% significance level...As you are Italian, this is a good lecture for you http://www.quadernodiepidemiologia.it/epi/assoc/chi_qua.htm

Comment: Grazie very much for the reply and the lecture :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,  your test is wrong. Here is the correct one

[image]

In the first two-way table (tabella a doppia entrata) you have your observed distribution. In the second one you have the theoretical one, assuming independence between the two characters, sex and bonus; in the third one there is your $\chi^2$ test, where the total value has to be compared with the critical value from a $(k-1)\times(h-1)=(2-1)\times(2-1)=1$ d.o.f. chi square distribution

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply! I guess I can't somehow grasp the difference between this kind of test and a Chi-squared goodness-of-fit one, in which I only compare the values from an observed distribution (in this case the bonus attribution between men and women?) with the expected, theoretical one!
I mean, abusing your patience: why do I have to use both Bonus and Malus distribution info when they're clearly related? I expected that knowing one (hence, considering one in calculating $\chi^2$) was "enough" since it should contain all the information...sorry for making no sense"

Comment: @luciadefinetti : I think that a quick lecture of the above link can explain you how this important test works. It is a very suitable test for various situations: checking independence, checking omogeneity and goodness of fit...finally in your data the cell with 4 observation is very borderline to apply this test...usually it is requested a minimum of 5...but 4 is good too...

Comment: @luciadefinetti : here http://calvino.polito.it/~riganti/Prob_Stat_teoria_esercizi.pdf is a very complete lecture that can be very useful for you: Cap 10 on non parametric tests. In particulare, Example 10.10 on page 301 shows you how suitable is chi squared test

Comment: Thanks again for the reply and all this material!